# cabal repl error

Tags: cabal, build, linux, repl

When I run cabal repl in the week01 folder I get an error message that states the following

```
*/plutus-pioneer-program/code/week01/dist-newstyle:
    createDirectory: permission denied (Permission denied)
```

I am not sure how to resolve this error.  The command looks to create a directory but the build does not have permissions to create that directory.

Any help you can provide is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Can you please provide steps to reproduce this failure? Which Operating System, which architecture, which repo cloned, which ref, and which command invocations?

Comment: Thank you for your interest in help resolve this issue.

Comment: Operating System
VM VirtualBox running Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Steps I take
Intiate nix-shell in the plutus-apps directory
Navigate to home/user/plutus-apps/plutus-pioneer-program/code/week01

or home/user/plutus-apps/plutus-pioneer-program/code/week02

At prompt enter: cabal repl

This is where I get the error message.

Comment: Do you have enough memory? Running all this stuff with require at least 8GB.

Comment: Yes, I believe I have about 12Gigs.  The problems seems to be tied to not having permissions to create files/directories during an installation.  When I run cabal repl, it throws an error protesting that cabal repl does not have permission to create directory dist-newstyle.